# Instance and Class methods, ObjC interface

Tags: ios

**Solution**

I did not differentiate between `instance variables` and `instance methods`. I kinda missed the point that `instance variables` can also be defined in a interface, unlike Java :)

```
#import "AnyHeaderFile.h"
@interface ClassName : SuperClass {
    NSString *myVar;
}
+ (anytype)doIt;
- (anytype)doItA:(anytype)a;
@end
```

**Original Question**

I have just started to learn ObjC and am reading [cheatsheet](http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/downloads/RW-Objective-C-Cheatsheet-v1_2.pdf).

So a interface separates instance and class variables with `{ instance methods } class methods`. So a definition like this should completely **invalid** right ? Since a interface definition does not need to use + - to define themselves as instance and class methods ?

```
#import "AnyHeaderFile.h"
@interface ClassName : SuperClass {
    + (anytype)doIt;
}
- (anytype)doItA:(anytype)a;
@end
```

Before I try code out, I am trying to get the basic fundamentals of theory correct.

Comment: You seem to understand the structure...did you have a specific question?

Comment: I thought + and - are incorrect ? Are they not ?

Comment: + and - are only used in method declarations. That's the only problem with your above code. + is static, - is not.

Comment: That's completely wrong, what goes inside the brackets are instance variables. You differentiate class and instance methods with + and -

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying to understand. I wanted confirmation if the interface definition was completely invalid. Please answer the question.

Comment: This code is invalid for reasons other than you indicate.  Where did you learn to put methods inside the braces?

Comment: I did not, I am trying to make a invalid interface just so I can get the concepts right.

Comment: I just realized, I was missing the point. Instance **variables**. I think I got it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both class methods and instance methods are defined in the same place. The +/- characters indicate what kind of method it is.

As a comment pointed out the curly brackets are for defining ivars. So your interface should look like this:

```
@interface ClassName : SuperClass  
{
    //Define your ivars here. 

    //Remember that in object oriented programming a class will have instance variables 
    //and methods. (In obj-c ivars can also be exposed as properties, which is a way of 
    //wrapping the access in a (perhaps auto-generated) method.)

    //ivars defined in the header can be accessed 
    //by subclasses - default 'protected' scope. 
}

+ (anytype)doIt;
- (anytype)doItA:(anytype)a;

@end
```

**To invoke the class method:**

```
//This sends a message to the ClassName singleton object. 
[ClassName doIt];
```

**To invoke the instance method:**

```
ClassName instance = [ClassName alloc] init];
//This sends a message to the instance of a class defined by ClassName
[instance doItA:someArgument];
```

Comment: Recently, it is more common to declare the instance variables inside the implementation instead of the interface (unless they need to be inherited)

Comment: Indeed, but if you want to access the ivar in a sub-class or category then you need to declare it in the header. (As stated in the code-comment above).

Comment: Correct, I just thought I'd note it since I know a lot of people will read this and think that they *must* be here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a static method, you try this code:

```
#import "AnyHeaderFile.h"
@interface ClassName : SuperClass
   + (id)instance;
@end
@implementation ClassName
static id _instance;
+ (id)instance {
   if (!_instance) {
      _instance = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
   }
   return _instance;
}
//...
@end
```